# Whatsapp redirect link like wa.me but with custom domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, whatsapp

Does anyone know the suitable or recommended way to make whatsapp redirect link like wa.me/PhoneNumber ..
is it using javascript redirect to the link?
or just use URL redirect using custom domain and then redirect to wa.me/phoneNumber

the use case is when user click the link (custom domain), it will open whatsapp and having conversation with us..

Comment: `wa.me` redirects to the `whatsapp://` protocol which is an application specific protocol. Different operating systems (especially the mobile ones) offer ways to register programs with protocols, so that clicking on `whatsapp://something` URI will be sent to the WhatsApp app.

Comment: but i can do something like redirect my domain to wa.me/phoneNumber right?
for example, whoever click on whatsap.mydomain.com will be redirect to wa.me/myPhoneNumber..is it okay to do that or better to make a js file that have redirect function to wa.me/myPhoneNumber..which one is recommended solution?

Comment: No, that would be perfectly fine. You could also redirect directly to the `whatsapp://send` link if you figure out how exactly that needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The correct HTTP redirect is a `303 See Other`, which is a HTTP/1.1 code. This is because your URI represents a description of your Whatsapp contact information, and the URL you're redirecting to is the actual location of that information.